# Chromium wont install ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS 32bit

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, google-chrome, chromium

Whenever I try install chrome, it throw me an error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
E: unable to locate package google-chrome-stable
```

I was running this command before:

```
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list 
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Using the software center just leads to a frozen download bar in the dashboard.

Comment: Google Chrome can't be installed on x86 anymore. Install Chromium or Opera instead.

Comment: You are trying to install Chrome, not Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome is no longer supported on the 32 bit platform.
There are some websites that are still hosting the .deb file:

```
wget https://archive.org/download/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb
sudo gdebi ./google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb
```

Edit: File not found from example I gave before.

Updated with working link

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install Chromium into 32-bit Ubuntu 16.04 by running

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

You are trying to install Chrome that does not support 32-bit systems any more.